# Using VB.net, I have multiple dynamically generated checkboxes that I need to get their current checked state

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I have googled this a bunch and cannot find a working solution. I have a VB.net 2010 .net4 project with a tabcontrol. I need to be able to add new tabs, with each tab having a couple of panels and a few buttons and checkboxs. Then I need to be able to determine the state of each checkbox on each tab. It all dynamically generates just fine, but I cannot figure out how to get the checkbox states on each new tab. I tried using addHandler, but I do not know how to get the value of a specific checkbox. Here is the code I have so far.

```
Public Class Form1
Public tabCount As Integer = 2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles          Button1.Click
    Dim hwnd = addTab("new tab")
End Sub
Function addTab(name)

    Dim newPanel As New Panel
    Dim toolbar As New Panel
    Dim reconnect As New CheckBox

    'ADD TAB
    tabCount = tabCount + 1
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(name & tabCount)

    'MAIN PANEL, BINDS WITH EXE
    newPanel.BackColor = Color.Black
    newPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    TabControl1.TabPages(tabCount - 1).Controls.Add(newPanel)

    'TOOLBAR
    ToolBar.BackColor = Color.White
    ToolBar.Width = Me.TabControl1.Width
    ToolBar.Height = 40
    ToolBar.Top = 0
    ToolBar.Left = 0
    ToolBar.AutoScroll = False
    newPanel.Controls.Add(ToolBar)

    'CHECKBOX
    reconnect.Text = "Reconnect"
    reconnect.ForeColor = Color.Black
    reconnect.Width = 180
    reconnect.Top = 10
    reconnect.Left = 10
    ToolBar.Controls.Add(reconnect)

    Return newPanel.Handle
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Tried reconnect.[Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx)?  You can subscribe to [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Please describe what you want in more detail to get a more concrete answer.

Comment: The first issue is that if I declare the checkbox locally like I did in the code above, I cannot access reconnect.checked. If I declare it publicly, I can access it, but then when I add a tab, the checkbox disappears from the previous tab. Not sure what to do here. Here is what I need to accomplish. When a checkbox on any one of the  tabs is checked or unchecked, I need to know which checkbox was changed and what the change was. There could be just one tab and checkbox or there could be 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In between these two lines:

```
reconnect.Left = 10
ToolBar.Controls.Add(reconnect)
```

Add this one:

```
AddHandler reconnect.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBox_CheckedChanged
```

Assuming you have this declared somewhere:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
  If chk.Checked Then
    'checkbox was checked
  Else
    'checkbox was unchecked
  End If
End Sub
```

You should be able to `DirectCast` `sender` to a `CheckBox` and identify your `CheckBox` by `Text` (or any other property).

**Note:** You don't need a public variable or anything like that for the above to work.

Comment: I had tried this at one point, but got stuck. Trying again... but not sure what to put in the CheckBox_CheckedChanged event. It gets called when any checkbox on any tab is clicked, but not sure how to determine which checkbox and which state it changed to. I'm sorry, but I do not know how to DirectCast sender to a CheckBox. This seems to be where I got stuck before. I think I am close here, just need a little more guidance. Thank You.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. I see how that works now. So half my issue is fixed. Any way to determine which checkbox was checked or unchecked? I guess when a checkbox is checked, that tab would be the active tab and I could determine it that way. But I would like something more elegant, since I could have multiple checkboxs on the same tab and then that would not work. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I added a unique name: reconnect.Name = "reconnect" & tabCount. Then I just referred to the name using chk.name. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @rerat: I'd go by `Name`, it should be unique, and not tied to user interface, so you can have your very custom naming scheme. **EDIT:** See, you already figured it out, I posted too late. :) Anyway, don't forget to accept and/or upvote my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'If you want to check for a checkbox.We have checked event

```
 If chkbx.Checked Then
    'Do what you want to do 
End If
```

Hopefully it helps

Comment: IsPostBack? I don't think the question has anything to do with ASP.NET.